# How to reduce the number of sprites when using css sprite technique

Tags: css, css-sprites

I notice that the file size of CSS sprite (.gif) keep growing over the period. That is because we keep adding new icons / sprites, and we never remove the existing sprites, because we are afraid of breaking existing design (offset recalculation or the sprites may be used somewhere that we overlooked).

I wonder how do we reduce the number of sprites? The image file size keep growing and growing.

Comment: Some answers I think are good but not directly answer my doubt, I will mark it as useful (the "up" arrow). Some answers seems quite promising but I have not had time to verify it (needs a lot of reading), I will mark it as useful too. I don't simply mark one as accepted without verifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do a manual check (do a search for the sprite name first, but once you have your results you will have to use pen and paper) to realise which images are being used. You can replace those ones for the new ones **without touching the positions for the rest**, but before doing that I would consider:

- Changing your gif to png-24 or SVG, as they weight less and have WAY better quality, specially with transparency involved. SVGs are also scalable, great for retina display devices, although not supported by all browsers (meaning IE) and therefore need an alternative.
- Using different sprites for different categories of images (for example, one for menu icons, another one for social icons, etc) so it's a bit easier to manage. You would be having two or three more server requests, not a real difference.

Comment: We have a huge ecommerce website. Any sprite removing will possibly require QA team to do full site check, which may not possible.

Comment: The idea of categorizing icon may reduce the impact of adding new sprites, I +1 for this. But yet, the particular sprite image will keep increasing.

Comment: You will eventually have to do it. Better sooner than later, specially since you need to keep adding icons without a 'system' to keep track of them. The only alternative I can think of is writing a script to do the detection automatically, but I can't imagine how. Maybe someone else has a better way. How many icons are we talking about? Are you replacing the code when you add a new one or leave old classes in the css?

Comment: I am getting ad-hoc request from Sales team, which they provide a new designs / icons. The problem is, if those icons make their way into sprite image, they will not be removed (in reality, no one go back and check if a particular icon in sprite images is used by any web page or not). The current image size is about 100k

Answer (score 1):

As from my experience, you have to do that one time clean up.
And then do things right !!!

Do OOCSS and use speaking names for specific sprite images.

I would recommend reading http://devblog.xing.com/frontend/a-so-called-sprite-revolution-on-xing/

After this, administrating the sprites will be muuuuch easier, but as I said, the one time effort is need.

Also, because GIF is not the format you want to use :-)